# After a couple thousand rows of my .tsv file, the dictionary i'm creating from those values begins to miss some rows

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a .tsv file that's storing genomic data. 13884 rows, 2 columns. Strain ID : Barcode.

I'm attempting to write all of these values into a dictionary using csv.DictReader:

```
strains = {}
with open("mutation_barcodes") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        key = row['strain']
        value = row['barcode']
        strains[key] = value
```

Maybe my logic is wrong here but my assumption was that I have would have an equal number of dictionary entries. Indeed, up until row 11918, the dictionary entries do match. After this line though there start to be some errors, ending up with about a thousand fewer dictionary entries than rows.

I've tried removing all lines from 11918 onwards; works as expected.
I've removed all lines before 11918, effectively running this on lines 11919-13884; also runs as expected.

I googled briefly if there was a max size of a dictionary but it seems like that isn't the issue. Any ideas? I imagine I'm implementing something incorrectly here.

** I believe my issue is that some of the strain ID's are repeated but with different mutational values, which is causing DictReader to overwrite the previous value of the strain id key

Comment: What values did the rows have ? Also what errors are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

i think the simplest solution is to use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
strains = defaultdict(list)
with open("mutation_barcodes") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        key = row['strain']
        value = row['barcode']
        strains[key].append(value)
```